# Need to stop scrolling when scrolling state in RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING state

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, scroll

I have searched lot on this ...... I can't find solution for this ....... Please help me

My Requirement 
1. I have to create vertical(Orientation) recycler view (Outter Recycler View).
2. For each item in **Outter Recycler View** I have to create horizontal(Orientation) recycler view(Inner Recycler View).
3. if user scrolling any **Inner Recycler View** I should scroll all **Inner Recycler View**.

I have completed 80 % of it but having problem in scrolling behaviour ................

when I am fastly swip InnerRecyclerView it's keep on scrolling at that time scrollingState is RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING and even if I made scrolling on another InnerRecyclerView app getting crashed. reason was recycler view keep on scrolling when user scroll fastly .

I need to know is it possible we can stop scrolling in RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING state.

```
   Code 


        class ScrollingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
            lateinit var listView : RecyclerView
            override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling)
                listView = findViewById( R.id.horizontalList)
                listView.adapter = HorizontalListAdapter(scrollListener)

        }

        var scrollListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                if (recyclerView.scrollState != RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    scrollAllRecyclerView(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                }
            }
            private fun scrollAllRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                scrollParent(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            }
        }
        fun scrollParent(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            // Scroll children RecyclerViews except the recyclerView that is listened.
            for (i in 0 until listView.getChildCount()) {
                val child = listView.getChildAt(i) as RecyclerView
                if (child !== recyclerView) {
                    scroll(child, dx, dy)
                }
            }
        }
        private fun scroll(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            recyclerView.scrollBy(dx, dy)
        }
        }


    activity_scrolling.xml

            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/horizontalList"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/vertical_scroll_list" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    HorizontalListAdapter


        import android.view.LayoutInflater
        import android.view.MotionEvent
        import android.view.View
        import android.view.ViewGroup
        import android.widget.TextView
        import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

        class HorizontalListAdapter (var scrollListener: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener) :
            RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

            class MyViewHolder(val recyclerView: RecyclerView) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(recyclerView)


            // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup,
                                            viewType: Int): HorizontalListAdapter.MyViewHolder {
                // create a new view
                val recyclerView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.vertical_scroll_list, parent, false) as RecyclerView

                if (scrollListener != null) {
                    recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(scrollListener );
                    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener );
                }
                return MyViewHolder(recyclerView)
            }

            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
                // - get element from your dataset at this position
                // - replace the contents of the view with that element
                holder.recyclerView.adapter = VerticalListAdapter()
            }

            // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
            override fun getItemCount() = 100

        }
vertical_scroll_list.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/verticalList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    tools:listitem="@layout/vertical_scroll_list_item"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


VerticalListAdapter

package com.cmi.myapplication

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class VerticalListAdapter () :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<VerticalListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    class MyViewHolder(val textView: LinearLayout) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(textView)


    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup,
                                    viewType: Int): VerticalListAdapter.MyViewHolder {
        // create a new view
        val textView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.vertical_scroll_list_item, parent, false) as LinearLayout

        return MyViewHolder(textView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun getItemCount() = 366
}

vertical_scroll_list_item

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp">
        <View android:background="@drawable/closed_line"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Error Log :**

```
 at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:5173)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1971)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:3391)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:14376)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3857)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3535)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3863)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3551)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:729)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1922)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4051)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:687)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:14644)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6456)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:6243)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5681)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5734)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5700)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5856)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5708)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5913)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5681)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5734)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5700)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5708)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5681)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8840)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8701)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8654)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8976)

at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:194)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:183)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:8916)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9003)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:996)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:794)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:722)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:981)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

Repeated Error Log :

```
2020-06-07 02:26:43.669 8362-8362/com.cmi.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1971)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollBy(RecyclerView.java:1812)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity.scroll(ScrollingActivity.kt:67)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity.scrollParent(ScrollingActivity.kt:62)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity$scrollListener$1.scrollAllRecyclerView(ScrollingActivity.kt:51)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity$scrollListener$1.onScrolled(ScrollingActivity.kt:47)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:5173)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1971)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollBy(RecyclerView.java:1812)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity.scroll(ScrollingActivity.kt:67)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity.scrollParent(ScrollingActivity.kt:62)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity$scrollListener$1.scrollAllRecyclerView(ScrollingActivity.kt:51)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity$scrollListener$1.onScrolled(ScrollingActivity.kt:47)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:5173)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1971)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollBy(RecyclerView.java:1812)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity.scroll(ScrollingActivity.kt:67)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity.scrollParent(ScrollingActivity.kt:62)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity$scrollListener$1.scrollAllRecyclerView(ScrollingActivity.kt:51)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity$scrollListener$1.onScrolled(ScrollingActivity.kt:47)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:5173)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1971)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollBy(RecyclerView.java:1812)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity.scroll(ScrollingActivity.kt:67)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity.scrollParent(ScrollingActivity.kt:62)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity$scrollListener$1.scrollAllRecyclerView(ScrollingActivity.kt:51)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity$scrollListener$1.onScrolled(ScrollingActivity.kt:47)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:5173)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1971)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollBy(RecyclerView.java:1812)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity.scroll(ScrollingActivity.kt:67)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity.scrollParent(ScrollingActivity.kt:62)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity$scrollListener$1.scrollAllRecyclerView(ScrollingActivity.kt:51)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity$scrollListener$1.onScrolled(ScrollingActivity.kt:47)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:5173)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1971)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollBy(RecyclerView.java:1812)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity.scroll(ScrollingActivity.kt:67)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity.scrollParent(ScrollingActivity.kt:62)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity$scrollListener$1.scrollAllRecyclerView(ScrollingActivity.kt:51)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity$scrollListener$1.onScrolled(ScrollingActivity.kt:47)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:5173)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1971)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollBy(RecyclerView.java:1812)
    at com.cmi.myapplication.ScrollingActivity.scroll(ScrollingActivity.kt:67)
```

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: "when I am fastly swip InnerRecyclerView it's keep on scrolling at that time scrollingState is RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING and even if I made scrolling on another InnerRecyclerView app getting crashed"  - it seems like you are trying to put duct tape on a bigger problem.

Comment: yeah right but I do no what to do ........ for this requirement what should I do??? @MarkKeen

Comment: If your app is crashing then you should provide the relevant code and stack trace

Comment: I have error log lot but all are looped.

Comment: @MarkKeen added code and stack trace